# Celery Error: no module name [django app name] - Have checked the if the celery file is correct but still get issue?

Tags: python, django, celery

When I Run `celery -A uno worker -l info` in the terminal I get the error

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in   import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named uno
```

Here is my celery.py which is in the uno app where the django settings.py file is.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'uno.settings')
app = Celery('uno')

# This reads, e.g., CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json'] from settings.py:
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# For autodiscover_tasks to work, you must define your tasks in a file    called 'tasks.py'.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
    def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

I am using Ubuntu but experience the same error on a Mac.
I install celery via pip in a virtualenv

I am not sure what is wrong or what I am missing here.
If I use the same celery file in a different project , name it works eg app = Celery('faketest')
. I am not sure what went wrong in this app. Maybe because I change the app name afterwards. I am truly stumped...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you aware that `uno` you are passing in `celery -A uno worker -l info` is the name of your application?

Comment: yes, I am following this tutorial https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ . Am i not meant to be doing this?

Comment: Can you add short directory/file structure of your django+celery app?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that if you have correctly named everything and you still have the module not found error (I spent hours trying to figure this out)... Then you must place the command "celery -A proj worker -l info above the apps branch

"The celery program can be used to start the worker (you need to run the worker in the directory above proj):" as per the docs